How To Reference One Asset File In For Assets
I recently discovered that with iOS 18, when displaying alternative icons in your app, you can no longer use Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: name)) as UIImage(named: name) now just returns nil (see here and here).
I am trying to figure out how I can get around this without having to have 2 versions of my icon in my app and therefore take up more space. Is there some way to reference one image in multiple places, such as having one be an icon asset and one be a non-icon asset that I can link to the same image in the directory?
The only thing I could come put with so far was to try and select the image itself from the asset directory when creating a new asset, but that just appeared to create a copy in the new location as well, which is no help. Not sure if there is a solution or not, just would be nice to keep app size down. Maybe I will upload a HEIF to take up less space. Anything would be helpful!

Your icon image should be no more than a few kb. Is it worth worrying about duplicating it?

@Paulw11 in total, my icons come out to roughly 18mb not (including dark and tinted variants), which is a good part of the app itself. Not a lot, but a decent amount

How many icons do you have? I would expect a typical iconset to be less than 300K

@Paulw11 I have about 31. I think I will just convert it to a more efficient format (I think HEIF uses less space) and go with that. I can't seem to find an alternative :(
